How would you say "after" as in "We are running *after* the clouds and they are chasing us."?
I am trying to translate the lyrics of the song "Tvoj osmijeh" by Zabočki Mališani into Latin. There is a verse in it saying:

Za oblacima trčimo i oni nas love.

I would translate it to English as:

We are running after the clouds and they are chasing us.

So, how would you say that in Latin? A literal tanslation might be something like:

Post nubes currimus et ii nos captant.

However, I am quite sure that's not proper Latin. So, what is?

I guess you felt post sounds little odd. (though I believe if one tries hard enough, they can find some examples) and perhaps the title of the question with the separation of "after" from "run" calls for it.  Did you consider any alternatives? Also, if "ii" refers to the nubes you might want to match the gender

It'd be more natural to treat "run after" as a phrasal verb and look for a Latin verb with a similar meaning (fugare, petere?) than to translate word by word. Have you tried coming up with English verbs with similar meanings and looking them up in a dictionary?

I'd say 'run after' in this context means simply 'pursue,' and so is just sequor or a compound of it, such as insequor. If you really want to include the notion of 'running,' you could add a form of currens; cf. Varro, Menippeae fr. 293: aut ille, cervum qui volabili currens/sparo secutus tragulave traiecit..., 'or that one who, having followed a deer at a run, pierced it with a flight-capable hunting spear or a dart....' There's also an adverb cursim, which literally means 'at a run,' though I'm not sure how often it's used with that meaning as opposed to 'quickly' or 'cursorily' in general.
